# Deep Learning Data Normalization

Tags: deep-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence, normalization, quantitative-finance

I’m working with different types of financial data inputs for my models and I would like to know more about normalization of them.

In particular, working with some technical indicators, I’ve normalized them to have a range between 0 and 1.

Others were normalized to have a range between -1 and 1.

What is your experience with mixed normalized data?

Could it be acceptable to have these two ranges or is it always better to have the training dataset with a single range i.e. [0 1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note that when we discuss data normalization, we are usually referring to the normalization of continuous data. Categorical data (usually) doesn't require the former.

Furthermore, not all ML methods need you to normalize data for them to function well. Examples of such methods include Random Forests and Gradient Boosting Machines. Others, however, do. For instance, Support Vector Machines and Neural Networks.

The reasons for input data normalization are dependent on the methods themselves. For SVMs, data normalization is done to ensure that input features are given equal importance in influencing the model's decisions. For neural networks, we normalize data to allow the gradient descent process to converge smoothly.

Finally, to answer your question, if you are working with continuous data and using a neural network to model your data, just make sure that the normalized data's values are close to each other (even if they are not the same range) because that is what determines the ease with which the gradient descent process converges. If you are working with an SVM, it would be better to normalize your data to a single range, so that all features may be given equal importance by the similarity/ distance function that your SVM uses. In other cases, the need for data normalization, whatever the ranges, may be removed entirely. Ultimately, it depends on the modeling technique you are using!

Credit to @user3666197 for the helpful feedback in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Currently the ranges that I’m using are [0 1] and [-1 1]. Do you think that it’s convenient to get all of them within [0 1] ? Thanks

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as accepted if your query has been fully answered!

Comment: With all due respect, the answer is NOT right - it both misinterprets the REASON WHY & omits other key facts. It is fair to say, some **ML-methods** directly & explicitly require normalised, mean-shifted data-pre-scaling to work at all, whereas some other do not ( confront details about Support Vector engines versus XGB or Random Forests - to name a few ). The omitted part ( also related to ways how to correctly solve the 1st problem ) is about how to prep categorical inputs ( disjunct categories that distinguish non-overlapping states - be them binary { On | Off } or enumerable hash-values )

Comment: Ah, understood. Apologies for the incomplete response. Do you recommend I remove the answer? Perhaps you could rework your comment into a separate answer? Do let me know what the right thing to do here would be.

Comment: @AliHaider - feel free to update your answer so as also to reflect the few objected weaknesses. You deserve a fair reward for such a completed work, so do not hesitate to work forth ( +1-ed already ). I do not try to compete on this - the life is so much more interesting in cooperative societies, my experience was just donated, as it made me spend some years fighting on this with SVMs & RF / XGB / Mondrian Trees' Forests. Also be informed, that if you do not put the @ username into a comment, the comment is not announced to the user, I came here just by chance. All the best to you & stay well

Comment: @user3666197 I updated the answer. Hope it is better now. Please feel free to let me know if there still any lapses. Thank you for your feedback; all the best to you too! :)